# How to change credentials for a given service in Cloud Foundry

Tags: mlab, cloud-foundry

I would like to know how (and if it's possible) to change the URI credentials from a service in Cloud Foundry. More specifically, mLab service (free plan) from Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

---

**Background**

I created and pushed a nodejs app to Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

This app is bound to a mLab service using free plan.

When the mLab service was created using Pivotal website, it created a database with an user and password automatically.

Opening app settings inside Pivotal website, I can see the following environment variables. Please notice the mongo uri inside `credentials` and `name` inside `mLab`.

```
{
  "staging_env_json": {},
  "running_env_json": {},
  "system_env_json": {
    "VCAP_SERVICES": {
      "mlab": [
        {
          "label": "mlab",
          "provider": null,
          "plan": "sandbox",
          "name": "users",
          "instance_name": "users",
          "binding_name": null,
          "credentials": {
            "uri": "mongodb://CloudFoundry_someusergenerated:apasswordgeneratedautomatically@somehost.mlab.com:someport/CloudFoundry_database_name"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "application_env_json": {
    "VCAP_APPLICATION": {
      "cf_api": "https://donotuseapi.run.pivotal.io",
      "application_name": "website",
      "application_uris": [
        "xxx.cfapps.io"
      ],
      "name": "website",
      "space_name": "space1",
      "uris": [
        "xxx.cfapps.io"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The connection with the database works fine with this default user and password. In order to get the mongodb uri from the environment variables, I am using npm package `cfenv`

```
const appEnv = require('cfenv').getAppEnv();
    const env = process.env;
    keys = { 
        mongodb: {
            dbURI: appEnv.getServiceURL(env.MONGO_SERVICE_NAME)
        }
    };
```

In my manifest.yaml file I have this `MONGO_SERVICE_NAME` specified accordingly with the service name inside the environment variables.

```
---
applications:
- name: website
  memory: 128M
  disk_quota: 256M
  random-route: true
  buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
  health-check-type: port
  env:
    MONGO_SERVICE_NAME: 'users'
```

Again, the db connection works fine.

===

Then I opened mLab website for this particular database and created a new database user.

Now I want to update the `credentials.uri` from VCAP_SERVICES (environment variables) for this particular service to use the new user and password.

As far as I coould see, `cf update-service` CLI command is not meant by that so I am wondering if this is a limitation from Cloud Foundry, Pivotal or mLab. I could bet that this limitation is due to the fact I am using Pivotal trial account and mLab free plan, however my question still the same if I upgrade plans.

Thanks,

Comment: Just unbind and rebind it, I would expect that to generate a new set of credentials.

Comment: I would like to use the credentials manually created inside mLab website

Comment: Why? The whole point of binding services is that you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: I still want to use service binding. I just wouldn't like to use an auto generated user/password. Imagine that I would like to do that only in a production cf space. Personally I think that it would be good to have more control on the user and password of the production db

Comment: Then just pull it from another env var (`DATABASE_URL` is conventional, and can be auto-set: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#DATABASE-URL) and override that. But it's unclear to me: why you don't want to use the generated credentials; why you'd explicitly get the credentials from the sevice if you don't want that; or why you'd deliberately introduce a difference between your environments.

Comment: Creating a new env var is OK however it wouldn't change VCAP_SERVICES. I have 2 cf spaces (a development and a production). I am using a mlab service instance in each of them, binded with the app pushed on both. The code is the same on both spaces - I only would like to have more fine control on the database connection from one of the services instances. It's not a huge problem but I wonder if cf/Pivotal/mLab allows that.

Comment: What "fine control" are you looking for? And no, it doesn't change VCAP_SERVICES, because the point of that env var is to reflect the *actual bound services*.

Comment: My question is on a general scenario but I can give you an example which I believe it makes sense to change the credentials uri: I could create a read-only db user in mLab. The user it generates by default is not read-only so I could try to change it for security reasons.

Comment: Some services accept parameters when bound, see e.g. http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/bind-service.html. I don't know if MLab does, but as far as I'm aware that's the only configuration you can provide that might alter the binding credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a user, it's not possible for you to change `VCAP_SERVICES` entries that are generated by a service brokers. These are fixed and not possible to change.

If you `cf create-service`'d a service, then it was created by a service broker and you get exactly what the service provider gives you. As was mentioned in the comments, depending on the service broker you may be able to pass arguments to the broker with `cf create-service -c`. Check the documentation of your service provider to see if there is an option to influence the credentials generated in the way that you would like.

If your service provider does not provide options to do what you want, you can create a service key instead of binding your service to an app. This will give you a set of credentials to your service that will last for the duration of the service key. The service key credentials are not automatically passed into an app, but you can feed them into your app in a variety of ways.

1. You can pass them in through environment variables.
2. You can create a user provided service (`cf cups`).
3. You can pass them through in application config or through a config server.

With all of these options, you are passing the credentials through to the app so you could in theory adjust or alter them before they get to your app.

Hope that helps!